# How to find some monomial in the ideal $\langle x^2-y,y^2-x\rangle \subset \mathbb R[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I don't know whether there is some general method to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: what do you mean by a monomial?

Comment: An element like $x^py^q$ for some $p$ and $q.$

Comment: @wilkersmon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial

Comment: Generated over which ring..?

Comment: over $\mathbb R[x,y]$

Comment: If I undestand correct, you want to find $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb R[x,y]$ such that $a(x^2-y) + b(y^2-x) = c(x^ky^l)$, for some $c\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Lærne such that $a(x^2-y)+b(y^2-x)=x^k y^l$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There aren't. Every element of that ideal vanishes on $(1,1)$, but a monomial doesn't.

Comment: And there I sat trying to form such a monomial. Clever

Comment: @wilkersmon Thanks. I thought it would require specialising in roots of unity, but it turned out to be simpler.